# Java recursion, return array index

Tags: java, recursion

In Java, I want to create a recursive method that looks for a specific integer in an array and when it finds it, it returns the array index.

My code so far is:

```
private static int contains(int[] data, int value, int index) 
{
     if (index >data.length)
     {
         return 0;
     }
     if(data[index] == value)
     { 
         return index;
     }
     else
     {
         return contains(data,value,index);
     }
}
```

The method does not return the right index.  what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `0` is a valid index, the first index in an array.  If you've gone off the end of the array in your base case, return `-1` instead to indicate "not found".  Also, you've gone off the end of the array when `index` reaches `data.length`, not when it has passed `data.length`, so you need to change your `if` condition here.

Second, your recursive call sends the same parameters, which will result in an infinite loop if the `value` isn't found in the initial recursive call.  You want to look at the next index in the next recursive call, so pass `index + 1` instead of `index` when calling `contains` again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you want to do a recursive method, you need two things:

1. A base case
   (in your method this is when `index == data.length` and `index == value`).
2. A recursive call if the value you have in the actual call is not a base case.

Then inside your method you have to do a **new call** to your method **with a new value of the variable that is incrementing or decrementing.**
In your case this variable is `index`.

Well, with all this, you have to think:

1. If **I start with a base case** my method works good?
2. If **I start with a no base case**, the successive calls going to a base case?

Your code would be something like this:

```
       private static int contains(int[] data, int value, int index){

 if(index == data.length) {
      return -1;
  }else if (data[index] == value){
      return index;
   }else{
      return contains(data,value,index+1);
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In recursion, you divide the problem into smaller similar problems, until you reach a point where the method/function can't or doesn't need to call itself anymore. In my version for **contains**, given below, each time the method is called, it checks if either it is past the end of the array ("before" the first element) or an occurrence of **value** has been found. If not, the method calls itself to look for the result. The method returns **-1** if the element is not found - this can be a suitable choice, since no array element is at index -1. Also, the method should be called with the length of **data - 1** as the third argument.

```
private static int contains( int[] data, int value, int index )
{
    /* Base cases - end of recursion: */
    if ( ( index == -1 ) || ( data[ index ] == value ) )
    {
        return index;
    }

    /* Recursion: */
    return contains( data, value, index - 1 );
}
```